# Routes in Pylons: Mapping to explicit .htm file

Tags: routes, pylons

How do I write a route to map to an explicit .htm file?

E.g. I have a something.htm under /templates in Pylons and I want to map http://myserver.com/something.htm to something.htm under /templates. Can I do this with Routes for Pylons or does everything get mapped to some combination of /controller/action/id ?

I would assume one way is to do:
map.connect('something.htm', '/something.htm', controller='something', action='something')
and create a dummy controller for it (which just returns render(/something.htm))?

This seems like cumbersome for this simple job.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is the best solution, but i have a mapping

map.connect('{name}', controller='something', action='identity')

which basically points to the name

def identity(self, name)
   return render('/' + name)

is there any security risk with this or what's the standard solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, that's what the /public directory is for.  Files in /public are matched before things in the `map.connect()` table.  So if you put foo.html in /public directly, http://www.example.com/foo.html will send you to that page.